# Swapping knights

Tags: mathematics, checkerboard, knight-moves

On a $3\times3$ grid we have:

[image: 33grid]

with $8$ moves needed to swap the red and blue knights.

What is the minimum numbers of moves to swap the knights on a $4\times4$ grid?

[image: 44grid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will take:

> **20 moves to swap the knights**

This can be done as follows:

> [image: Zerris]

All credit goes to @klm123 for demonstrating a good way to visualize this in [a similar puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25287/switch-the-knights/25313#25313).

Comment: You seem to be missing some connections - B2 to C4 and D3, and C3 to A2 and B1. This does actually put opposite-coloured squares in reach of B2 and C3.

Comment: Right you are - no idea how I missed that.  As a result, we can make the solution more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is, in chess terms,

> 20 half moves, or 10 move pairs.

In algebraic notation:

> ```
>  1.  N3b2 N2c3
>  2.  Na1  Nc1 
>  3.  Nb3  Nbd3 
>  4.  Ncb4 Nc2 
>  5.  N1d2 Nd4 
>  6.  Nb1  Nd2 
>  7.  Na3  Ncb1 
>  8.  Nbc4 Nac3 
>  9.  Ndb2 Nc2 
>  10. Na4  Nd1
> ```