# Knights Problem

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

There are **2 white knights** and **2 black knights** positioned at a (`3 X 3`) chess board. Find the **minimum** number of moves required to `replace` the blacks with whites and the whites with blacks.

I tried the above in 19 steps and reckon that I'm wrong. Please help !!

[image: Picture is here]

I guess the catch here is to position the knights in

0w0
w0b
0b0

or

0b0
w0b
0w0

`0 -> empty space` | `w -> white knight` | `b -> black knights`

What is your take on this? [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uPv3z13-vDyDjK9510_gn-oZRX_UuFiJ) is my solution, but it seems that my answer takes longer number of steps.

**EDIT**

For some of those who still have some doubts regarding the question, the final configuration should be:

`BoW
 ooo
 BoW`

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! If you haven't already done so, please take the tour! You'll also get a free badge :). Normally, asking questions like these are slightly frowned upon as in can bring a lot of speculations or a variety of answers. This one might be okay though, so I would need some confirmation.

Comment: Do you have to source of the puzzle by chance?

Comment: @North Didn't get your first comment. What type of question is this? Is it not suitable to ask at this platform. Sorry, but I don't have any source.

Comment: This is a classic puzzle, which I think I've seen discussed in a Martin Gardner book/column, and maybe also in one of H.E. Dudeney's books. Variants of this puzzle have been posted here before, e.g. [Desegregate the knights](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/desegregate-the-knights) with a different goal, and [Switch the knights](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25287/switch-the-knights) on a 3x4 board, and [Swapping knights](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28383/swapping-knights) on a 4x4 board.

Comment: @jay No, no, this puzzle is fine, I was just concerned it might warrant a lot of different answers. clearly it didn't though :)

Answer (score 11):

If you numbered the board like this:

> [image]

Then it is easy to notice that:

> The route of each knights is a **cycle** of:
>  $\dots - 1 - 6 - 7 - 2 - 9 - 4 - 3 - 8 - \dots$
>
>  (i.e. from $2$ can go to $7$ or $9$ and etc.)

Therefore:

> We want to move white from $1\&7$ to $9\&3$, for black from the $9\&3$ to $1\&7$.
>  It is straightforward that the minimum movement we should take is shifting them all $4$ times to right or left.
>
>  Hence, $4 \times 4 = 16$ moves is the optimal one.

Comment: that's a much better proof than what I did - which was to sit down to a 3x3 chessboard I happened to have leftover from a woodworking project.  Proof > brute force.

Answer (score 4):

Although @athin seems to have proven it impossible, I can't find any problem with my solution in

> 8 moves

Here it is:

> [image]
>  **1. Na3 Nc3
>
>  2. Nc1 Na1
>
>  3. Nc2 Nb2
>
>  4. Na2 Nb3**

Since the path is cyclic, there are working positions reached along the way too, of course.

Comment: Eh, can the starting positions be different than the one given by OP?

Comment: @athin, OP seems to have given three different starting positions, and there's nothing forbidding it, so, yes, I guess?

Comment: OP gave 1 starting position, and 2 "almost there" positions that they were aiming at (neither of which were ever actually reached in the solution I devised - I suspect that it was "forcing" those positions that pushed OPs score up to 19 instead of 16)

Comment: @Chronocidal, ah, it is indeed possible to interpret "I tried the above" as meaning "I tried the above, *which also had the fixed starting position below*", and "position the knights" as "position the knights *by moving them from the fixed starting position*". Judging from OP's later edit, this might even be what OP meant. That didn't really occur to me at all.

Answer (score 3):

I can get you down to 16 moves.  I don't know if I can do any better.

Start off by

> moving all four corners onto the black squares, giving
>
>  oWo
>
>  BoW
>
>  oBo

Then, instead of returning to the original square, move

> them onto a corner one rotation away from where they started.  This gives:
>
>
>  BoB
>
>  ooo
>
>  WoW

Eight moves total, so far.

Follow the same process for four more moves, and you wind up with:

> oWo
>
>  WoB
>
>  oBo

and then, four more moves (for a total of sixteen):

> BoW
>
>  ooo
>
>  BoW